# Notify call disconnected Twilio Android

Tags: android, twilio

I have implemented Twilio thrid party SDK for making outgoing calls in android. When i make a call when the number is switched off or refused the call gets disconnected after some time automatically i have been trying to fetch this event.To fetch this event i tried implementing The ConnectionListener interface and has override all the method but when the call gets disconnected or connected  i was not able to get any logs printed. After implementing the ConnectionListener i have implemented the following method in my code.

```
@Override
public void onConnected(Connection arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Log.i("test", "onconnected");

}

@Override
public void onConnecting(Connection arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Log.i("test", "onconnecting");
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected(Connection arg0) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
      Log.i("test", "onDisconnected");
}

@Override
public void onDisconnected(Connection arg0, int arg1, String arg2) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
     Log.i("test", "onDisconnected");

}
```

Can anyone help me on this issue. Thank in advance.

Comment: Please add some more code on how you implemented the listener. These are just overriden methods so won't be able to figure out anything on the basis of this.

Answer (score 0):

check if you have callbacks to notify your app of outgoing connections.
you should have something like this:

```
connection = device.connect(params, this);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just implementing the override functions of Connection listener is not sufficient.
But you need to set the listener to the connection. Like
either

```
connection = device.connect(parameters, this /* ConnectionListener */);
```

or

```
connection.setConnectionListener(this /*ConnectionListener */);
```

Hope this helps...